# Add optional group of characters in regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

Hi there I was trying to check only [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) or facebook.com the rest is optional for the following criteria

- [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)
- http://www.facebook.com
- http://facebook.com/
- https://www.facebook.com
- https://facebook.com/
- facebook.com/myname.89

`const checkFacebookURL = new RegExp(^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)facebook.com?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9](.?))?([a-zA-Z0-9](.?)))`

```
if (facebookRegex.test(e.target.value)) {
   setFacebook(e.target.value);
   setFacebookError(false);
} else if (e.target.value === '') {
   setFacebook(e.target.value);
   setFacebookError(false);
} else {
   setFacebookError(true);
}
```

I'm not that good with regex was reading the docs and trying to figure it out but no luck.
If someone could point me in the direction or better share an answer that would really help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this pattern:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com(?:\/.*)?$
```

Explanation:

- `^` from the start of the URL
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` optional `http` or `https` scheme
- `(?:www\.)?` optional `www` subdomain
- `facebook\.com` match `facebook.com`
- `(?:\/.*)?` optional slash and subdirectory
- `$` end of the URL

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FoZcrR/1).